# ExtJS4 direct form submit

Tags: extjs4

Common form with Ext.direct submit n load, load is working properly, but submit is return error, coz in post data in undefined

```
var _form = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
 api: {
   submit: submit, //actions I took from code that going above, and never mind what I ll write here. Its not a problem
   load: load           
    },
    baseParams: {
        st_id: st_id,
        id: id
    },
    paramsAsHash: true,
    defaultType: 'textfield',
    buttons: [{
        text: 'Cancel',
        handler: function() {
            this.up('form').getForm().reset();
        }
    }, {
        text: 'Save',
        handler: function() {
            var values = this.up('form').getForm().getValues();
            this.up('form').getForm().submit({
                success: function() {
                    grid.getStore().load();
                }
            });
            this.up('form').getForm().reset();
        }
    }]
});
```

in to headers wrote that content type is "application/json;" but in other cases its "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", last it make sense, right? and it work, but in other forms.
all of this is under Kohana, so when I look clearly what is going on in controllers, in Extdirect Router I see what for this form there is no info about submit method.

Answer (score 0):

it was kind of stupid mistake: I forgot @formHandler in a definition